# Multer [NodeJS] for multiple fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Multer for multiple fields.

I want to upload images via the file field (one image), as well as upload an image via "Summernote".

This is all one controller. How to implement work with multer?

`upload.single ()`, `upload.array ()`?

How to implement correctly?

When I upload via "Summernote" I get the error:

> MulterError: Unexpected field", because there is a conflict with the
>   fields.

At the momemt:

```
router.post('/create', upload.single('cover'), post.savePost)
```

Comment: Whats via "Summernote"?

Comment: @Rashomon https://summernote.org/ — wysiwyg editor with uploads images

Comment: You might be looking for [`upload.fields()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#fieldsfields).

Comment: @StockOverflaw Thank. I solved this problem in this way. Posted below.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue:

```
router.post('/create', upload.fields([{
    name: 'cover',
    maxCount: 1,
}, {
    name: 'files'
}]), post.savePost)
```